# System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() - Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely.

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory-leaks, stack-overflow

I have an ASP.NET web application developed in C# and .Net v4. When you login in and leave for the page for some 15-20 minutes, I get the "**Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely.**"

According to my knowledge, there is no way you can try-catch the stackoverflow in .Net. I would imagine that recursive loading of web page and active session checking leading to this error (maybe a bad coding practice). I have also added the screenshot as i am able to figure it out from Stack trace. If anyone help me in this,it will be helpful.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: What control is it trying to find? I'd imagine you have a `while`, `for` or `foreach` loop that isn't ending and running until this is encountered.

Comment: This isn't catching a stack overflow. It's using [`RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficentExecutionStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack.aspx), which throws a `InsufficientExecutionStackException`, *not* a `StackOverflowException`. This exception can be caught. This is testing to ensure there is enough stack to do do an operation without actually running out of stack. However, catching this exception probably won't be helpful because there likely isn't a meaningful way to handle it.

Comment: What is likely going on is that `LoadRecursive`, a framework method, is using this to ensure proper stack space. It's failing *possibly* because you have very, very nested ASP.NET controls.

Comment: @StevenVondruska - I dont have any looping that affect my code. also the loops which i have are having proper termination statement. Definitely not any infinite loops in every page - perhaphs in the master page.

Comment: @vcsjones - I could use RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficentExecutionStack and try-catch the InsufficientExecutionStackException as you mentioned. It is an useful information to know, but it is highly impossible as the project is just upgraded from .net v2 to .net v4 and we have 100s of different pages if we want to try catch the exception. I doubt on login session checking method in the master page..! i will try edit the post and add that method. hope you guys help me!!??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. Still the test. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707970/memoryfailpoint-throws-insufficientmemoryexception-unconditional)
they really looks promising. I will keep you guys updated when I succeed..

**Thank you all for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this callstack is right at the end of the stack.

A few things to look for:

1. Is there anywhere in your code where you are using `.FindControl(string id)`?
2. If so, is it locating a control and then trying to locate it further?
3. Are you dynamically creating controls, like for `<asp:Placeholder/>` controls.

It can be recursive when you reference the parent from within a nested control, which then gets re-referenced by the parent.